# Javascript function working on one page but not when included on main page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm relatively new to using javascript and having an issue when using it alongside php.

I am creating a budgeting calculator that allows users to select items(e.g cinema ticket) from a menu. I have created a database with a list of common goods and their associated price and am using php to pass this this information into my website.

I found a javascript function online that subtotals a user's total expediture as they select more items. So as a user selects a checkbox beside an item,the subtotal is autmoatically updated at the bottom of the page.

To ensure security, I am running the php query which prints out the information on a seperate page and using the include() function to include it on the main page.

The issue I am having is that when I run the page which only has the php code on it and include the javscript function on this page it works correctly, however, it won't work when it is included on the main page.

Here is a demo of the version of the subtotal form I am using - https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/checkbox/group.php

//html

```
<html>
   <!-- submenu for transport-->
<button class="collapsible">Transport</button>
  <div class="content" >
    <!-- further submenu for public transport -->
            <button class="collapsible" > Public Transport</button>
     <div class="content">
        <table class="auto-style2" style="width: 96%">
        <tbody class="auto-style2">     
         <tr>
               <td style="width: 353px; height: 26px;">&nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 26px">
           <div class ='row1'>€</div></td>
         </tr>
            <?php
               include('publictransport.php');
             ?> 

        </tbody>        
        </table>
    </div>  
</html>
```

//php

```
<?php
//This is publictransport.php
//establish connection
include('detail.php');
##query information
$q  = 'SELECT name,price FROM expenditure WHERE sub_category = "public_transport"';
$result = $db->query($q);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<form action='' method='post' class='demoForm' id='demoForm'><div id = 'transport'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    //loop and print out information in html format
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class = 'firstcolumn'>", $row[0] ,"</td>";  
    echo "<td class = 'row1'>",  $row[1],"</td>";
    echo "<td class ='row1'> <div id='ck-button'> <label> <input type='checkbox'";
    echo "value = '". $row[1]."'><span> + </span></label></div></td></tr>";
}

echo "</div><p><label>Total: $ <input type='text' name='total' class='num' size='6' value='0' readonly='readonly'/></label></p>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

//javascript

```
<script>
// call onload or in script segment below form
function attachCheckboxHandlers() {
// get reference to element containing transport checkboxes
var el = document.getElementById('transport');
// get reference to input elements in transport container element
var types = el.getElementsByTagName('input');

// assign updateTotal function to onclick property of each checkbox
for (var i=0, len=types.length; i<len; i++) {
    if ( types[i].type === 'checkbox' ) {
        types[i].onclick = updateTotal;
    }
 }

}

// called onclick of transport checkboxes

function updateTotal(e) {

// 'this' is reference to checkbox clicked on

var form = this.form;

// get current value in total text box, using parseFloat since it is a 
string

var val = parseFloat( form.elements['total'].value );

// if check box is checked, add its value to val, otherwise subtract it

if ( this.checked ) {
    val += parseFloat(this.value);
} else {
    val -= parseFloat(this.value);
}

// format val with correct number of decimal places
// and use it to update value of total text box

form.elements['total'].value = formatDecimal(val);
}

// format val to n number of decimal places
// modified version of Danny Goodman's (JS Bible)

function formatDecimal(val, n) {
n = n || 2;
var str = "" + Math.round ( parseFloat(val) * Math.pow(10, n) );
while (str.length <= n) {
    str = "0" + str;
}
var pt = str.length - n;
return str.slice(0,pt) + "." + str.slice(pt);
}

// in script segment below form

attachCheckboxHandlers();

</script>
```

The issue is that on the main page, the javascript does not locate the checkboxes. The value 'types' which is an array of the checkboxes should be of length 4. On the publictransport.php page it has a length of 4 whereas on the main page it returns an empty array.

Any help would be really appreciated and as I am new to javascript I may not have explained the issue in the best way!

Comment: 2 possible solutions: 1 would it have something to do with the fact that there is no <body> tag in the supplied HTML code, and 2: is it possibly because you are making a form in the middle of a table? I don't think 2 should create an error, but you never know...

Comment: @Chipster There actually is a body tag, this is just a small portion of my code. Thank you for the help anyway!

Comment: I figured as much. I just was making sure since you were having problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<div>` tags are not allowed inside `<tbody>`, so the rendered HTML differs from the expected one.

This is how Firefox 65 renders your HTML
[image]

Note that firefox simply ignored entirely the `<form>` and the `<div>` tags, and placed the `<tr>` 2 parents up.

The simplest way to patch this, is to remove the `<form>` and the `<div>` tags entirely, and just place the `id = 'transport'` on the `<tr>`, that way the JS should work.

If you need the form, you should then place it like this

```
<html>
   <!-- submenu for transport-->
<button class="collapsible">Transport</button>
  <div class="content" >
    <!-- further submenu for public transport -->
            <button class="collapsible" > Public Transport</button>
     <div class="content">
        <table class="auto-style2" style="width: 96%">
        <tbody class="auto-style2">     
         <tr>
               <td style="width: 353px; height: 26px;">&nbsp;</td>
           <td style="height: 26px">
           <div class ='row1'>€</div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
            <?php
               include('publictransport.php');
             ?> 
           </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>        
        </table>
    </div>  
</html>
```

And the in `publictransport.php` add a `<table>` inside the `<div id='transport'>`